# Why java 7 123.123456f will got 123.12346?

Tags: java-7, floating-point-precision, floating-point-conversion

I am working on a LibGDX program in Java 7 64 bits.

When I use junit to test a function which receives a float as parameter, I got a strange result. I call the function using `123.123456f` as parameter, the function receives `123.12346`. Why does this happen?

When I use `12.123456f` as parameter, it got the correct result. 
`123.12345f` still works.

Hence I use `System.out.println(...)` to check the input.

It is not important to me, but I just want to know why. Thank you very much!

Regards,
Antony

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: there are already numerous questions about this "problem" on this site. Floating-point types don't have infinite precision. Floats have 24 bits of mantissa and can only hold 6-7 digits of precision

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`f` means `float` which means single-precision [IEEE-754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) floating-point number. They aren't very precise, they only have roughly seven significant digits. You can double that (!) by using `d` for `double`, which is a double-precision floating-point number, giving roughly 15 digits of precision. Provided, of course, that whatever you're passing this into accepts `double`s and not just `float`s. If it needs any reasonable precision, it should.

Note, though, that even doubles have issues; they have *greater* precision, not perfect precision. IEEE-754 floating point is designed for rapid calculation and compact storage. The classic imprecision example, even with doubles, is `0.1 + 0.2`, which comes out as `0.30000000000000004`.

If you were dealing with currency figures (I think, with that library, you aren't), you might look at `BigDecimal`, which works more like we're used to working, with an arbitrary number of digits. They're much bigger and much slower, and have their own issues (like the fact they can't accurately represent `1 / 3`), but for currency they can be a better choice.

Comment: Your answer sounds like floats are useless and doubles will solve all problems. Usually floats are totally enough and if you want exact values, then doubles will run into the same problems, just a little bit later. You should at least add a hint to BigDecimals in your answer.

Comment: @noone: `BigDecimal` has, of course, its own problems, like trying to accurately represent `1/3`. :-) I don't think I said doubles solved all problems, far from it. But they are more precise than singles.